# Redirect to www in iis?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I know there been quite a few posts on this already but the answers do not work for me.

when I type in `example.com` in the url I want it to redirect to https://www.example.com

I have these rules but when I put in `example.com` I get 404.

```
    <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern" negate="false" pattern="OFF" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

edit

I also [tried this](https://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html) but still not getting expected re

Answer (score 0):

According to your url rewrite rule I found you set a url rewrite rule at first. That means if your url match the (.*), it will rewrite the url to /index.html and will not go to any other url rewrite rule. So your "Redirect to www" and "Redirect to HTTPS" rules will not be fired.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to use below rules. It will fire the redirect rules firstly, then fired rewrite rule.

```
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
  <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" ignoreCase="true" matchType="Pattern" negate="false" pattern="OFF" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
    <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

> I have these rules but when I put in example.com I get 404.

As far as I know, 404 means page not found, I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing to track the actually url IIS have redirect to.

Details, you could refer to below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules